# Doubt on d-separation

Tags: independence, bayesian-network, separation

In the book: *Bayesian Networks With Examples in R*, the author shows three examples of d-separation:

He cites:
[image]

Then, just a few lines below, the author uses the **dsep** function, which returns FALSE for one of the examples previously given!!
[image]

Is this a mistake in the book? If not, what am I missing, why is his explanation so confusing?

Comment: I think the figure just tries to show the different types of connections and is not claiming that d-separation exists in all of the examples. On the top of page 23, the authors state clearly that A and S are only d-separated if we are not conditioning on E. The figure legend should probably be worded more clearly.

Comment: I agree with you, but just below 'figure 1.3' he says "some examples of d-separation covering...", so in a sense he is in fact claiming that d-separation exists in the three examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legend is wrong (or very misleading), while the code snippet displays the correct output. In the third example, given $E$, the highlighted node in grey, $A$ and $S$ are not d-separated.

In this elementary configuration, $E$ is called a *collider*, and
 in a collider, conditioning on the common effect $E$ makes $A$ and $S$ dependent on each other. See for example this [course](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/16/lectures/21.pdf) p. 483.

Comment: Thanks, your example is clear, but then; why do you say "it is not a mistake"? The right-most figure is not d-separated; therefore the author claiming that the right-most is d-separated is a mistake from the author.

Comment: Edited, I was talking the code output